# I confused how to combine viewpager and listview in a fragment

Tags: android, android-listview

I ran into a problem,when I use viewpager and listview in the same fragment.
First,update your listview;
Second,change viewpager's currentitem,and then your listview will change its position.
How can I hold my listview in the same position?
Here it is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/knowledge2_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/title_height"
        android:background="@color/titlebg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="知识"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titletextsize" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/knowledge2_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/knowledge_image_height"
        android:layout_below="@id/knowledge2_title" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@id/knowledge_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/knowledge_image_height"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/knowledge_rl1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/knowledge_image_texth"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/knowledge_pager"
            android:background="#80000000">
            <TextView
                android:id="@id/knowledge_pagertext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="13dip"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@id/knowledge_radiogroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@id/knowledge_rb1"
                    style="@style/image_dotstyle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@id/knowledge_rb2"
                    style="@style/image_dotstyle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@id/knowledge_rb3"
                    style="@style/image_dotstyle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@id/knowledge_rb4"
                    style="@style/image_dotstyle"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <com.yeahis.swimcoach.widget.MySwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@id/knowledge2_swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <ListView
            android:id="@id/knowledge2_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:divider="@null"/>
    </com.yeahis.swimcoach.widget.MySwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

com.yeahis.swimcoach.widget.MySwipeRefreshLayout is same like android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is to create 2 layouts: one handle content in `viewpager` and one is for `viewpager` combined with `listview`:

```
layout_1.xml
<LinearLayout...>
   Content to be refresh in this layout
</LinearLayout>

layout_2.xml
<LinearLayout...>
   <ViewPager .../>
   <ListView ..../>
</LinearLayout>
```

You create an adapter to handle viewpager and content in the viewpager that display `layout_1.xml`, whenever you swipe, the `listview` will stay the same.

To update the `listview` you can monitor with [`onPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

Comment: Sorry,I am not very clearly what you mean.Could you describe in more detail?